# Emgu opencv capture RTSP/HTTP media stream too slow

Tags: opencv, emgucv

My code works ok for built in cameras but I want to capture a stream from an IP camera. However the feed runs very slow. How can I skip frames so I am always seeing the latest frame. For what I am doing it is not important to have a perfect streaming video but rather get frames in realtime.

```
        while (true)
        {
            // try to open the camera device
            if (capture == null)
            {
                try
                {
                    int index;
                    bool isNumeric = int.TryParse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CameraSource"], out index);
                    capture = isNumeric ? new Capture(index) : new Capture(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CameraSource"]);
                }
                catch
                {
                    frameObservers.ForEach(a => a.frame(cameraNotConnectedBitmap, new List<Person>(), recognizer.isActive()));
                }
                Task.Delay(1000).Wait();
                continue;
            }

            // read a frame from the camera
            Mat matFrame = capture.QueryFrame();
            Image<Bgr, byte> frame = (matFrame == null) ? null : matFrame.ToImage<Bgr, byte>();
            if (frame == null)
            {
                frameObservers.ForEach(a => a.frame(cameraNotConnectedBitmap, new List<Person>(), recognizer.isActive()));
                capture = null; // force to reconnect to camera again
                Task.Delay(1000).Wait();
                continue;
            }

            frameObservers.ForEach(a => a.frame(frame, personsInCurrentFrame, recognizer.isActive()));

            Task.Delay(10).Wait();
        }
```

Comment: We did similar things, and I'm facing the same problem. I didn't wait for 1000 unit of time, but still works crappy with no luck. Have you already solved your problem?

Comment: Yes use a mjpeg stream and it is pretty fast.

Comment: Grab and display the frame at the same time will also solve the problem even with rtsp stream. Anyway thanks for your response.